# android-studio "Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment" with swaywm

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, android-studio

I'm running Arch Linux with the sway window manager on wayland. I followed both the official Google instructions for installation and the Arch Wiki (also to get the dependencies), but both ways leave me with

```
$ ./studio.sh
Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

I have installed java

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode)
```

And also tried serveral stuff on the internet (user rights - now running in home directory) and also the often recommended

```
$ export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
```

in addition to

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-12-openjdk
```

Normally I would have long assumed that android studio does not work with wayland, but several posts on the internet suggest otherwise, e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/swaywm/comments/8wo3cx/android_studio_problems/).

I assume this may be a minor problem, but I have tried for so long and now want to ask for someone with more experience to point me in the right direction.